Is there a way to compile LaTeX code generated by ChatGPT directly in the browser?
I've been using ChatGPT to generate LaTeX code for various projects, and I often find myself having to copy and paste this code into separate LaTeX editors to compile it and see the results. This process can be quite tedious and disrupts my workflow.
Additionally, I've noticed that some LaTeX renderers, like KaTeX, sometimes fail to fully render complex LaTeX formulas, which is another inconvenience.
I'm wondering if there is a way to compile LaTeX code directly within the browser, especially when using AI tools like ChatGPT, without having to rely on external editors or experiencing incomplete rendering issues.
Has anyone come across a tool or extension that can help streamline this process?

There are latex editors with build in AI features, for example texstudio. Instead of copying from a web browser, you could  directly use it in your editor.

KaTeX is not a LaTeX. So it is expected, that it can handle only some LaTeX code and also behaves different than LaTeX in several circumstances. On the other hand, ChatGPT often hallucinates code, that even LaTeX cannot render without errors. But have you tried asking ChatGPT for the PDF of the code …

Yes, there is a solution that addresses these exact issues. I recently developed a browser extension called LaTeXGPT that is designed to simplify the process of compiling LaTeX code directly within your browser.
Features of LaTeXGPT:

Seamless Integration: The extension automatically adds a "Compile" button to LaTeX code blocks on any website. This button allows you to generate PDF or HTML outputs instantly with a single click.
Full LaTeX Support: Unlike basic JavaScript libraries, LaTeXGPT uses a server-side solution to provide comprehensive LaTeX support, ensuring accurate and complete rendering of complex formulas.
Direct Code Compilation: You can compile LaTeX code generated by ChatGPT or any other AI tool without leaving your current site. This makes it incredibly efficient for users who frequently work with LaTeX.
Flexible Viewing Options: You can view your compiled documents in a new tab, providing a full-screen, distraction-free experience.
Customizable Activity: The plugin allows you to choose which websites it is active on, giving you control over where it functions.

How It Works:

Install the Extension: You can find LaTeXGPT in chrome web store.
Navigate to a Site with LaTeX Code: Once installed, the extension will add a "Compile" button next to LaTeX code blocks.
Click to Compile: Simply click the button to generate a PDF or HTML output of the LaTeX code.


LaTeXGPT streamlines the workflow for those who regularly use LaTeX and interact with AI tools like ChatGPT. It eliminates the hassle of switching between multiple tools and ensures that LaTeX code is rendered accurately and efficiently.
Feel free to ask if you have any questions or need further details!

welcome to tex se. although you are upfront about your connection to the product, asking a question simply to promote any product, but especially your own, doesn't feel entirely appropriate to me. (fwiw I am not among the down-voters.)

I don't know, I was a little hesitant too, but I did this because this free app might make things easier for someone.
